# Error while deploying rails app at cloudfoundry with redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, cloud-foundry

I am getting this error while creating service for my app
Create services for application?> y
Creating service redis-70a08... OK
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash

```
NoMethodError: undefined method name' for nil:NilClass 
vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/service/bind.rb:18:in bind_service' 
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in send' 
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in run' 
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:68:in `invoke'
```

Comment: I got this error                                                                  NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/cli/service/bind.rb:18:in `bind_service'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `send'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in `run'
mothership-0.3.5/lib/mothership/command.rb:68:in `invoke'

Comment: are you running ruby 1.9 or 1.8? would it be possible that you uninstall all the vmc and its dependencies and reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

you may try a newer version VMC, gem install vmc --pre

I encountered the same error with 0.4.7, but 0.5.0 works fine for me.